# Getting file reference error after H10 app crash error while trying to deploy on Heroku

Tags: python, html, reactjs, heroku

I'm getting this error after running the heroku logs --tail command.

```
2021-05-18T13:06:18.026204+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/api/app.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-05-18T13:06:18.026205+00:00 app[web.1]: from HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler
2021-05-18T13:06:18.026205+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HelloApiHandler'

2021-05-18T13:06:50.495217+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/" host=deploy-testv1.herokuapp.com request_id=7790eadd-a43b-49db-8eb0-27fff8d7a6bf 
fwd="123.201.36.104" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-05-18T13:06:50.785798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET 
path="/favicon.ico" host=deploy-testv1.herokuapp.com request_id=0d7d0f68-a99b-4783-af40-cb80f17b825b 
fwd="123.201.36.104" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the `app.py` file in which I'm getting error on line 5:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS 
# from api import HelloApiHandler
from HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler

# app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='../build')
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='../build')
# CORS(app) 
api = Api(app)

@app.route("/", defaults={'path':''})
def serve(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder,'index.html')

api.add_resource(HelloApiHandler, '/flask/hello')
```

And here is the `HelloApiHandler.py` file:

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

class HelloApiHandler(Resource):
  def get(self):
    return {
      'resultStatus': 'SUCCESS',
      'message': "Hello Api Handler"
      }

  def post(self):
    print(self)
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('type', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('message', type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args)
    # note, the post req from frontend needs to match the strings here (e.g. 'type and 'message')

    request_type = args['type']
    request_json = args['message']
    # ret_status, ret_msg = ReturnData(request_type, request_json)
    # currently just returning the req straight
    ret_status = request_type
    ret_msg = request_json

    if ret_msg:
      message = "Your Message Requested: {}".format(ret_msg)
    else:
      message = "No Msg"
    
    final_ret = {"status": "Success", "message": message}

    return final_ret
```

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn api.app:app
```

I feel I'm correctly importing the HelloApiHandler file but still heroku log is throwing an error. What's the reason?

The directory structure:

```
api
  venv
  app.py
  HelloApiHandler.py
  requirements.txt
build
node_modules
public
src
Procfile
package.json
requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has any questions

Comment: I think you are importing `HelloApiHandler` from `HelloApiHandler` but there is only `get` and `post` in `HelloApiHandler` so that's why it is not finding module.

Comment: I have used this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/build-deploy-a-react-flask-app-47a89a5d17d9. I did it the way they did. Also, the application runs fine in localhost but throws error for heroku. If the link doesn't get opened, try opening it in incognito mode.

Comment: In above example they are importing like `from api.HelloApiHandler import HelloApiHandler` and in your example it is different. so maybe that is an issue?

Comment: Yes, that's because their HelloApiHandler file is in a different directory whereas my HelloApiHandler file is within same directory.